# Sugar on a Stick install from MacOS

Tags: fedora, osx

Help! Has anyone recently made a bootable USB for Sugar on a Stick (SoaS with Fedora 30) using a Mac? Is running a Fedora VM and doing there the right thing to do?

Comment: I downloaded the VirtualBox image for Fedora 30 from https://www.osboxes.org/fedora/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using Fedora Media Writer for OS X. Get the `dmg` file from https://github.com/FedoraQt/MediaWriter/releases

Comment: Thanks, @mattdm! I'll try it tonight

Comment: I keep losing this URL, and it's hard to find https://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Sugar_on_a_Stick/Downloads

Comment: Try https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/soas/

Comment: Well, either way. The USB sticks I put it on get a success message after a "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer" error box popup, so it... probably worked. It doesn't look like I'm going to be able to boot a MacBook to it, but I have a Chromebook on the way for this very reason

Comment: Is that the case using the Fedora Media Writer?

Comment: Yes. The target x131e Chromebook can read it. It can't boot from it because of UEFI SecureBoot, but I'm going to come at it with Mr Chrome Box and see if that helps. https://mrchromebox.tech/ In any case, your solution for writing it worked, although I can't read either one (I used two) from the MacOS itself.